# Dynamically loaded JS needs to be clickable just like it's in the html

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page fires off an ajax query, where the MySQL Db is queried and the results are returned.  (all successful).

Those results are formatted for output as a shopping gallery/catalogue and also as an accordion filter menu.  So I can filter the shopping catalogue display. eg say I want to see only items that are red.

All is working so far.

My problem is with the filter accordion menu - dynamically created in js.
When I click on any selectable item in the tab-content, nothing happens.  This means the parameter that should be sent, isn't being sent.

If I hard code the accordion filter or even load it with my server-side language, into the html directly, the filtering does send off the parameter and so the shopping catalogue is adjusted accordingly but, in that scenario, I am unable to dynamically change the filter menu.

I think the code I shall post below is the relevant code that recognises changes in the originally loaded content and fires off the ajax but (I think) it doesn't understand any changes to textboxes in the dynamically loaded content.

Please help me to understand what I need to add that will make dynamically loaded content fire-off to the ajax calls.

```
var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");

function update_nav_filter(opts) {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/php-queries/product-filter-query.php",

    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {
      filterOpts: opts
    },
    success: function(records) {
      //console.log(records);
      //alert('SUCCESS!');
      // alert(records);
      $('#filters_div').html(makeFilter(records));

    }
  });
}

$checkboxes.on("change", function() {
  //alert('there is a change is checkbox status');  // working on page load but not when any checkbox is clicked-on 
  var opts = getCatalogueFilterOptions();
  updateCatalogue(opts);
  update_nav_filter(opts);
});

$checkboxes.trigger("change");
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an event listener.

Following page-load, I select an item in the JS generated nav filter.  eg pedal_bins in the sub_category section.  I am then shown a display of pedal_bins. :)

Then I select 'kettles', another sub_category but I can only see the last sub_category that I click on. The pedal_bins disappear.

How best can I build and remove items with a single click?  Store in a session parameter and then 
a. remove the latest click if it matches whats in the session
b. add the latest click if its not already in the session

Then submit whatever the array is at that stage?

Or, is there a better way to run this?

Here's the listeneer

```
enter code here

document.getElementById("filtering_div").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
// e.target was the clicked element
if (e.target && e.target.matches("input")) {
    var parameter = e.target.id;
    //console.log("Anchor element", parameter , " was clicked" ); 

    var opts = getCatalogueFilterOptions(parameter);
    console.log(opts);
    // update_nav_filter(opts);
    updateCatalogue(opts);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a "delegation" problem. When you create a dynamic element, in order to be able to act on the newly created element, you have to reference it as a child element that was originally loaded with the DOM.

For example, if you have an element called `<div id="top"></div>` and you create a dynamic element, let's say `<button id="test">Click</button>` in there, you'll have to refer to that div when adding an event listener.

```
$("#top").on('click', '#test', function(){
   //event related code goes here.
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbtrzozt/) I created that explains the whole thing with some examples.

If you have any questions about it, please let me know.

Comment: You should add the important explanations in the answer, and not in the external fiddle. The `.on()` is the general purpose function to create any type of event listeners in jQuery, not only those with delegation. `.click(` is a shortcut for `.on('click',  function() {`

Comment: I can't seem to get my head around it in the timeframe I have set for myself.  Can we discuss paid-for projects anywhere in this forum?  Perhaps somewhere where I can be quoted for the work and we may take it from there?  I can send link to the page when appropriate. :)

Comment: @headache, I am not sure we can discuss on the forum, but maybe in chat? Just let me know if you want to go into chat.  At moderators, if this is not fine, just delete this comment.

Comment: Sure, we can take this comment in to chat. Let me know.

Comment: You could also email me at "Difster at unseen.is"  --I  normally don't actively monitor that email, but I'll keep it open this afternoon.

Comment: Thank you both for your response, however, I have successfully overcome that difficulty once I broke through a mental blockage and was pointed to delegation issues by Diftser. PM sent to Difster.